# Ignoring source code in the debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How can I get the Visual Studio debugger to ignore certain source files? In other words, I would like it to behave as if the functions defined in those files had no debugging info, so that:

- When stepping into code, it will ignore functions defined in those files (a smart pointer `operator->` is an example where this is useful)
- If the debugger stops due to an exception or `_asm int 3` in one of these files, it shows a function further up the callstack instead (handy for assert code)

VC6 had a (undocumented?) feature along these lines, if my long term memory isn't playing tricks on me.

I'm using Visual Studio 2005, but the answer for each version of Visual Studio, if different, would be useful.

Comment: VC's debugger is not the best... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx)'s a tutorial / explanation from an msdn blog.